# Should the exception constructor throw exceptions?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

The **constructor of an exception** should be allowed to throw exceptions?

Example:

```
public class MyException : Exception
{
   public List<string> Errors { get; private set; }

   public MyException(List<string> errors)
   {
      if(errors == null)
      {
         throw new ArgumentNullException();
      }
      else if(errors.Count == 0)
      {
         throw new ArgumentException("At least one error must be present");
      }
      Errors = errors;
   }
}
```

Those exceptions (`ArgumentNullException` and `ArgumentException`) thrown in the constructor can do harm while using `MyException`?

This is use case of this exception:

```
class Program
{
    private static void ErrorHandling()
    {
        List<string> lst = new List<string>();

        // ... here do some checks and insert the errors in the list 'lst'

        // This check prevent the ArgumentNullException and
        // the ArgumentException to be thrown
        if (lst.Count > 0) 
        {
            throw new MyException(lst);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            ErrorHandling();
        }
        catch(MyException e)
        {
            foreach(string s in e.Errors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The **harm** I talk about is: if for some reasons the programmer that use `MyException` doesn't check the input list (`if (lst.Count > 0)`) it can lead to an unwanted `ArgumentNullException`/`ArgumentException`.

I think this can lead to bugs where the programmer is trying to throw `MyException` with wrong parameters but instead it throw an `ArgumentNullException`/`ArgumentException`.

Should I:

- Don't do checks in the constructors of the `MyException` and leave the managment of the `Errors` property entirely by the user
- Do the checks and throw `ArgumentNullException`/`ArgumentException`, knowing that this can lead bugs

Comment: @DaltonCézane OP is asking about throwing exceptions from the constructor of an Exception class specifically. The links you provided talk about throwing exceptions from constructors in general

Comment: Yes, you both are right. Thank you for the warning.

Comment: It is perfectly acceptable to throw exceptions in a constructor provided that they are **indicating that the caller has a bug**.  In your case, that's exactly what you're doing.

Comment: @Bruno that would be the same in this case as well

Comment: @Simone - This doesn't look like a duplicate of the linked question (which is for Java not c#) but it does feel primarily opinion-based as defined, say, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315569/what-classifies-as-opinion-based-open-discussion), since it's basically a question about coding standards & best practices.  Is there a need to re-open this?

Answer (score -1):

> Those exceptions can do harm while building the MyException

I don't see you are building an exception at all and moreover your `MyException` class makes very little sense. What you are doing can simply be done using probably another `private` method. Then why build a application exception for this unnecessarily?

```
public List<string> CheckErrors(List<string> errors)
{
      if(errors == null)
      {
         throw new ArgumentNullException()
      }
      else if(errors.Count == 0)
      {
         throw new ArgumentException("At least one error must be present");
      }

 return errors;
}
```

Comment: I am building the exception MyException. I don't unserstand what are you talking about, can you provide an example?

Comment: @Simone sure ... something like in edited answer. You aren't doing anything special than this actually

Comment: I updated the question to be more clear